# Swift button shadows

Tags: swift, xcode, button, layer, shadow

I have two simple buttons, both has shadows and both using the same parameters for those shadows. Is it possible to merge these parameters together? It feels like it would be much simpler to control them that way...

these are the buttons:

```
@IBOutlet weak var locationButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!
```

and this is the code for the shadow:

```
    locationButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    locationButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 2)
    locationButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1.8
    locationButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3

    infoButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    infoButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 2)
    infoButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1.8
    infoButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
```

Once again, the code is working without any problems, I just want to have less lines with controlling the two layers simultaneously.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extension

```
extension UIView {
  func addShadow() {
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 2)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.8
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
  }
}
```

Then call it

```
locationButton.addShadow()
```

You can also create a `UIButton` subclass

Comment: oh, thats really simple, thanks! I guess with more experience these things will come naturally, or at least I hope so... :)